# How to solve an error when loading a package under development from git?

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install the `interference` package in `R`. The package is still under development, so one needs to install it from the website:

```
devtools::install_github('szonszein/interference', ref='0.1.0')
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘randnet’ is not available for package ‘interference’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/interference’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/sw/x2n7fwsj6p32wmcz0dfyk5p40000gn/T//RtmpVf6Xns/file58297d4fcf4a/interference_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Even when I install `radnet`, however, things do not work. Any advice on how to deal with this?

Comment: Note: Don't use the git and/or github tags just because a repository is hosted on GitHub (see the tag descriptions).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that install, and it failed because `randnet` is not available. `interference` hasn't been updated in more than 2 years, so I think you'll have some work ahead of you: fork its repository, replace all references to `randnet` with something that is available.

`randnet` was removed from CRAN about 6 months ago because the authors were unresponsive to bug reports from CRAN.  So an alternative would be to install the most recent (buggy!) version by downloading https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randnet/randnet_0.5.tar.gz and installing that `tar.gz` file, but it appears the authors are no longer maintaining it, as is also the case for `interference`.  I'd find a different solution.